# dublicate entries and alocate to another user

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a question: I would like to duplicate all the data in the table `PlanData` `where userID='38'` and change then the `userID` of the duplicated data into `userID='39'`. So `UserID` is one of many many cols in the table.

How would I be able to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Select the row set you want (including the where clause to limit it to user id = 38), explicitly specifying each column name, then instead of `userID` use the constant value 39. Once you have the results that you want to insert, put an `INSERT INTO <TABLE>` above it, specifying the column listing in parenthesis. Job done.

Comment: What datatype is column `userID`? You write `userID='38'` and a bit further you write `userID=39` . So it seems like int to me, why then do you use quotes ?

Answer (score 3):

Try below -

```
insert into PlanData(userid, col2,col3)
   select 39 as userid,col2,col3 from PlanData where userID='38'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to hardcode the column names then you could use a temporary table as a first step.

The example snippet below also uses a temp table for PlanData, for testing reasons.

```
-- Test table
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PlanData') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #PlanData;
CREATE TABLE #PlanData (ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), userID INT, Col1 VARCHAR(30));

-- Sample Data
insert into #PlanData (userID, Col1) values
(36,'A'),(36,'B'),(36,'C'),
(38,'X'),(38,'Y'),(38,'Z');

-- Create a temporary table with data from the original user
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpPlanData') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpPlanData;
SELECT * INTO #tmpPlanData FROM #PlanData WHERE 0=1
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM #PlanData WHERE userID = 38;

-- Remove the identity column from the temp table
-- This assumes that the ID column is the first column in the table
ALTER TABLE #tmpPlanData DROP COLUMN ID;

-- Set the userId to the new userId in the temporary table
UPDATE #tmpPlanData SET userID = 39;

-- Insert all from the temporary table into the destination table
INSERT INTO #PlanData 
SELECT * FROM #tmpPlanData;

-- Check the inserts
SELECT * FROM #PlanData
WHERE userID = 39;
```

Comment: thanks a lot, sadly I got this error for it `Msg 8101, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
An explicit value for the identity column in table 'PlanData' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.`

Comment: @Andreas Updated, now with the assumption that the PlanData has an identity column named `ID`.